# Am I using the mouse functions correctly?

Tags: click, mouseevent, pascal

It is expected to show 1/2/3 corresponding to the option that has been chosen, but nothing shows when I clicked on it. Is it the coding problem or something else?

I have tried with **getmouseY** instead. Still, nothing shows up.

```
uses
  mouse;
var
  event : tmouseevent;
  check : boolean;
begin
  initmouse;
  write('Option 1 ');
  write('Option 2 ');
  writeln('Option 3');
  check := true;
  repeat
    getmouseevent(event);
    if (event.buttons=mouseleftbutton) and (event.action=mouseactiondown) then
      case getmouseX of
        0..8 : writeln('1');
        10..17 : writeln('2');
        19..26 : writeln('3');
      end;
  until not(check);
end.
```

It should show 1 when clicked on option 1 and 2 when clicked on option 2 and so on but nothing shows when I click on it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using FPC + Lazarus.

I can reproduce the problem you describe but confess I am puzzled by its cause.

Try the following:

- Make sure the project options in Lazarus are set correctly to include the paths to `mouse.pp` and its
  two include files `mouseh.inc` and `mouse.inc`.
- Put a debugger breakpoint on the line `b:=PendingMouseEvents` of `SysGetMouseEvent` in Mouse.pp
- Compile and run the project

When the breakpoint trips, use F8 to single step through the code.

For me, the value of `b` is always zero.  This is where it gets a bit mysterious:

If you search the source code of Mouse.PP and the two inc files for any assignment
to `PendingMouseEvents`, the only places it is assigned a value are `SysInitMouse`
and `ClearMouseEventQueue` and in both cases the value it is set to is zero, which
is why `SysGetMouseEvent` never exits and returns to your code.  That's why your `case` statement never executes.

I'm not sure whether this is an oversight by the code's authors or what.  I think
you should try asking in the Lazarus support forum, https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php

As far as I can see, you are using the mouse functions correctly, but they just don't work properly.